# Want to create S3 Filesystem in python with stable library

Tags: python, amazon-s3, shared-libraries, python-s3fs

I want to create s3 file system for uploading files to s3 bucket using the pyarrows write_to_dataset function

```
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
pa.parquet.write_to_dataset(table, root_path=output_folder, filesystem=fs,
                            compression='snappy', partition_filename_cb=lambda x: filename)
```

but I got to know that s3fs library is still in the beta phase.

is there any production/stable library available for creating a s3 file system?

if not is there other way like boto3 to create s3 file system?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Where did you read that S3FS is in beta? There's already been 18 releases and the latest release is currently 1.91, far from beta. Is there a reason you are trying to find alternatives? S3FS is production ready.

Comment: here Development Status = beta  on https://pypi.org/project/s3fs/

Comment: or maybe i am refering to wrong library here version mentioned as 2022.11.0

Comment: Ah OK - I understand. Try reaching out to Martin Durant, the maintainer (mdurant@continuum.io) and ask their advice on using S3FS within production. Most likely, it's still in beta because of the lack of enterprise support.

Comment: Note the difference between s3fs fuse and s3fs-python.